# Default CSS values for a fieldset <legend>

Tags: html, css, legend, fieldset

I'm trying to use a `<legend>` as a title inside a `<fieldset>`.

In browsers other than IE, the `<legend>` is positioned on the top border of the `<fieldset>`, with the text perfectly centered on the line.

[image]

I'm trying to reset it's position so that it sits just like any other element. i.e. an `<h3>`.

**Here's the CSS I have so far.**

```
fieldset legend {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: static;
    border: 0;
    top: auto; left: auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

But the ***legend*** is still perfectly centered on the line.

> Yes, I can add a margin/padding/top coordinate but I want to know if the browser has any default values for the element that trigger this layout. I want to then, override these values.

***Tested in Firefox (3.6.10), Chrome (6.0.472.63), Safari (5.0.2)***

**Update**
I'll leave this question open for another week just in case someone HAS been able to style `<legend>` elements. If no solutions are found I'll accept @jnpcl's answer.

Comment: Are you targeting IE? Or are you targeting Firefox, Chrome and Safari only?

Comment: @LeguRi, I'm targeting all modern browsers, so all of the ones you've mentioned. Using my CSS properties above, IE has placed the legend where I want it.

Comment: I've almost given up on the `legend` tag because of it's unwillingness to be styled. In the last form I worked on, I threw my keyboard at the monitor and used `h3` s instead...

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Guess what, there's a broken coffee-cup on the floor and I'm using `<h3>` tags.

Comment: The LEGEND tag is poorly supported in most browsers. You'll be fighting it every way. I eventually opted to use header tags instead. Not ideal semantic-wise, but seemed the most pragmatic route.

Comment: I found this useful and helped me solve the same issue http://www.mattheerema.com/articles/web-design/2006/04/getting-fieldset-backgrounds-and-legends-to-behave-in-ie/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://web.archive.org/web/20140209061351/http://tjkdesign.com/articles/how_to_position_the_legend_element.asp

> Simply put, it is not possible across
>   browsers to position the LEGEND 
>   element in a Fieldset.

Workaround: wrap the text from `<legend>` in a `<span>`, then reposition the `<span>`.

Comment: hate to be mean but did you read the whole question? `Yes, I can add a margin/padding/top coordinate but I want to know if the browser has any default values for the element that trigger this layout. I want to then, override these values.`

Comment: From the article I linked, it appears that the default values are not override-able.

Comment: If he's targeting "all modern browsers" then I'm with @jnpcl on this one. +1

Comment: I'll remove my downvote since you deleted the code which used positioning.

Comment: The link appears to have died at some point since this answer was posted.

Comment: @MichaelCordingley I fixed the link.

Comment: Just an FYI that wrapping the `<legend>` tag in a `<span>` works for positioning, but it breaks accessibility using a screen reader / narrator. It won't be able to natively group the parent `<fieldset>` with the `<legend>` tag.

Answer (score 39):

This is enough :

```
 form legend{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: This is the better answer, even in 2018.

Comment: Should be the selected answer. I tested across IE11, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. This does the job for a simple text legend.

Comment: Yup, This is best answer !

Answer (score 2):

I've just styled my `<legend>`'s by giving them a `position: absolute; top: -25px;` and the the parent `<fieldset>` with a `position: relative; padding-top: 30px;`

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, but still high in Google, so I'd like to share a solution that works for me (targeting only more modern browsers for the best experience).

```
fieldset: {all:unset};
legend:{all:unset};
```

this does the trick for me, unsetting all values to defaults. From there on I can happily style on a "clean-sheet".

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification, [here is the default styling](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-fieldset-and-legend-elements) of the `fieldset` and `legend` elements. By resetting those properties, you can have a clean `legend` element to work with.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTML - Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-fieldset-and-legend-elements), the below styles are working like a default:

```
fieldset {
    display: block;
    margin-inline-start: 2px;
    margin-inline-end: 2px;
    border: groove 2px ThreeDFace;
    padding-block-start: 0.35em;
    padding-inline-end: 0.75em;
    padding-block-end: 0.625em;
    padding-inline-start: 0.75em;
    min-inline-size: min-content;
}

legend {
    padding-inline-start: 2px; padding-inline-end: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#rendered-legend), the legend is only a "rendered legend" if it is `float: none`.

This means that by doing:

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend style='float: left'> Heading </legend>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <!-- Your form elements here -->
</fieldset>
```

This makes the legend behave like a normal (if floated) element.

Note: `clearfix` is the Bootstrap clearfix class:

```css
.clearfix::after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
```

(A similar answer was posted already, but this does not include the clearfix trick, and the reference to the specification which shows that this is not a random but, but specified behaviour that is reliable.)