# How do I have fieldset::before rule account for the legend?

Tags: html, css

I'm placing content in ::before rules on each of the fieldsets in my form, but they seem to be placed under the legend of the field, not as the first child like I would expect. I would like to have the ::before content justified with the top of the legend, not the top of the input elements. It isn't enough to shift the ::before content vertically across the board because my legends are different heights. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to get the behavior I want?

Expected behavior:

```
before    legend
          legend
          legend

          input
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>This is the legend.</legend>
        <input type="text" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
       <legend>This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long legend.</legend>
       <input type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</form>​
```

CSS:

```
fieldset
{
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 120px;
}

fieldset::before
{
    margin-left: -40px;
    float: left;

    content: "before";
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GYzTA/2/

EDIT:

I found a "doh" solution of just changing the CSS selector, but I'm still curious why the fieldset::before rule seems to insert the content after the legend.

```
fieldset legend::before
{
    margin-left: -40px;
    content: "before";
}​
```

Comment: I can't tell what behavior you want. Do you want the pseudo-elements to show up on the same line as the first line of each legend, or above the legends?

Comment: I would like the ::before content to be justified with the top of the legend (and fieldset); I updated with a visual.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Referencing [Default CSS values for a fieldset <legend>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973456/default-css-values-for-a-fieldset-legend)

> Simply put, it is not possible across browsers to position the LEGEND element in a Fieldset.

Solution: Use `<span>` instead of `<legend>`

Comment: If there were a sister tag to `legend`, I'd think it would be a heading rather than a `span`. The answer you cite says something quite different, you should re-read it. By the way, is that a Serra Avatar in your profile picture or is it just me? :)

Comment: Interesting, it looks like it automagically styles it to be situated on the top border (without override?). I guess that's why the ::before content was ending up below it. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @atonparker: `legend` is a strange beast, this may not be the last of your design nightmares that are caused by it.

Comment: If you use a `span`, you lose all the accessibility benefits of `legend`. Luckily there is a decent solution — see the most upvoted answer on the question you linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20705034/466453