# Delete legend tag's properties

Tags: html, forms, legend

I need to make one of my h4 tags for a form be a legend tag but the default properties of the legend tag is so different. I'm doing this to meed accessibility standards. Is there a way to strip the legend tag of all of it's properties so it's just like a h4 tag? I've tried putting the legend tag inside h4 and using inherit but that doesn't work.

Comment: Consider rewriting your post to be a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3973527/2096258.

But the short answer is that the `<legend>` tag cannot be completely stripped of its styles. If you place your `<h4>` inside the `<legend>` (which I think would be more semantic anyway) and then wrap the `<legend>` in a `<span>` (as stated in the page I included above), then you might be able to use the `<span>` to adjust any positioning issues that are caused by the `<legend>` tag.

Hope this helps.